# Реализация seekBar в mediplayer (fragments)

Tags: java, android

Запускаю программу,seekbar вижу,но когда воспроиз. мелодию то положение и какое -либо реагирование на перемещение не дает результат.Хочу при перемещ.бара проматывать мелодию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Разметка где seekbar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lldinamik"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/belarus"
                />
            <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/russia"
                />
            <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/japan" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/litva" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/england" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/finland"

            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/france" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:max="100"
             />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/mediaTime"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код класса:

```
public class Fragment2 extends PageFragment {
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.fragment2);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {


        seekBar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seekBarPlayer);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                seekChange(v);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void seekChange(View v) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }

}
```

Класс в котором плеер и в котором мелодии присвоена каждой картинке

```
//массивы мелодий
    private int[] soundsRawResIds = new int[]{R.raw.belarus, R.raw.russian, R.raw.japan,
            R.raw.litva, R.raw.england, R.raw.finlandia, R.raw.france};
    //каждой кнопке присвоена своя мелодия
    private int[] buttonIds = new int[]{R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7};
    private int[] fragments = new int[]{R.id.imageView1, R.id.imageView2, R.id.imageView3};
//public class PageFragment extends Fragment 
if (pageNumber == 1) {

                rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);//контейнер
//присваиваю идентификатор
                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {

                    arr_imageB[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            stopAnimation();//остановка анимации
                            // mSeekBarPlayer.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);

                            switch (v.getId()) {

                                case R.id.b1: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);//старт анимации
//воспр. конкретную мелодию заданному элементу массива
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
                                    break;
                                }

                                case R.id.b2:

                                {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);

                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b3: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b4: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b5: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                                    break;
                                }

                                case R.id.b6: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b7: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);
                                    break;
                                }

                            }


                        }

                    });
                }


                return rootViewB;
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

//метод в котором воспроизвожу мелодии

```
 private void playSample(int resid) {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            stopAnimation();

        } else {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                // mediaPlayer.seekTo(getProgress());
                afd.close();


            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

    }
```